# asp.net core foreach data in partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

Problem is how to `foreach` Model data to that partial view. I'm using ASP.net CORE.

**ProgramController**

```
public IActionResult Create(){
var items = context.Customs.ToList();
return View("Views/Account/Partial.cshtml",items);
}
```

**Register.cshtml**

```
<form asp-route-returnUrl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]" method="POST">
...

@Html.Partial("Partial")

...
</form>
```

**Partial.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<ClaimBased.Models.CustomModel>

@foreach(var items in Model){
   <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => items.Name)</p>
}
```

Comment: What is your question? What problems are you having?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'm trying to foreach model data in partial view. but its not working.

Comment: What is not working? What are you expecting and what is actually happening? What if any errors are you getting? (no one can answer this unless you explain your problem in the question)

Comment: I'm not getting any error. I think my `return("view",data);` is not working.

Comment: `@Html.Partial(..)` does not call a server method

Comment: @StephenMuecke What do you mean sir? Do i have to like this? `@Html.Partial("Partial",Model);` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170253/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-ruka-xing).

Comment: Html.Parial will not execute the action method. If you want to execute an action method, Consider switching to `Html.Action` or view components

Comment: @Shyju But sir there is no `@Html.Action` i guess. I found `ActionLink`

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do ? What is Model data you want to foreach  ? What is your Register view strongly typed to ? How is it related to the `Create` action you shared ? What exactly is your expected behavior ?

Comment: Build a view component and invoke that in asp.net core. It is similar to Html.Action in pre-asp.net core.